# ActiveAdmin belongs_to relationship input based using string box on attribute other than id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin in a standard rails app.

I have items belongs_to user relationship

On the admin#items form (edit and new) instead of having a select with all user emails, etc I want to instead have a string text field where an admin can input a user email instead of an id or selecting one from a dropdown.

On save I want to validate that email belongs to a user and assign the item to that user if it does.

I have

```
f.inputs "Item Details" do
    f.input :user, as: :string
end
```

However that shows the user object in the view and I want to take in an email.

Or

```
f.inputs "Item Details" do
    f.input :user_id, as: :string
end
```

takes in the ID when I want the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I added a parameter that was not an object attribute, in this case the object's user's email.

```
f.input :user_email, as: :string, :input_html => { :value => f.object.user.try(:email) }
```

Then in the controller for the update and edit methods I handled the processing of that parameter. Additionally i deleted the param before super was called in order to avoid issues with the model. This assigns the user to the item via the user's email.

```
def update
  user = User.where(email: params[:item][:user_email]).first
  if user
    params[:item][:user_id] = user.id.to_s
    params[:item].delete(:user_email)
    super
  else
    flash[:notice] = "That email does not belong to a valid user"
    redirect_to admin_group_path(params[:id]) 
  end
end
```